# Expand width of multiline textview below another horizontally aligned view if space is available

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

One multiline textview and an another custom view are aligned horizontally in a linear layout. Height of custom view is 100dp. What I want to achieve is to expand width of lines of multiline textview which are below custom view to match parent.[image]

This is a rough sketch of what I want to implement.
Is there any way to achieve this?